# Best way to pass parentheses in URL?

Tags: javascript, url, urlsearchparams

I have turn to the API, which apparently accepts parameters for a redirecting request as one of the parameters. I prefer use the `URL` object to create requests. To add and encode parameters, I use `searchParams`. But searchParams encodes, among other things, the parentheses `(` and `)`, which eventually leads to request error.

What i try to do:

```
const country = 'us'
const language = 'en'
const anchor = 0
const consumerChannelId = 'd9a5bc42-4b9c-4976-858a-f159cf99c647'

const count = 24

const remoteSearch= `/product_feed/rollup_threads/v2?filter=marketplace(${country})&filter=language(${language})&anchor=${anchor}&consumerChannelId=${consumerChannelId}&count=${count}`

const url = new URL('https://example.xyz/v1')
url.searchParams.append('queryid', 'products')
url.searchParams.append('country', country)
url.searchParams.append('language', language)
url.searchParams.append('endpoint', remoteSearch)
```

And what i got:

`https://example.xyz/v1?queryid=products&country=us&language=en&endpoint=%2Fproduct_feed%2Frollup_threads%2Fv2%3Ffilter%3Dmarketplace%28us%29%26filter%3Dlanguage%28en%29%26anchor%3D0%26consumerChannelId%3Dd9a5bc42-4b9c-4976-858a-f159cf99c647%26count%3D24`

What i should got:

`https://example.xyz/v1?queryid=products&country=us&language=en&endpoint=en&endpoint=%2Fproduct_feed%2Frollup_threads%2Fv2%3Ffilter%3Dmarketplace(us)%26filter%3Dlanguage(en)%26anchor%3D0%26consumerChannelId%3Dd9a5bc42-4b9c-4976-858a-f159cf99c647%26count%3D24`

My solution:

```
const country = 'us'
const language = 'en'
const anchor = 0
const consumerChannelId = 'd9a5bc42-4b9c-4976-858a-f159cf99c647'

const count = 24

const remoteSearch = `/product_feed/rollup_threads/v2?filter=marketplace(${country})&filter=language(${language})&anchor=${anchor}&consumerChannelId=${consumerChannelId}&count=${count}`
const endpoint = encodeURIComponent(remoteSearch)

const url = new URL('https://example.xyz/v1')
url.searchParams.append('queryid', 'products')
url.searchParams.append('country', country)
url.searchParams.append('language', language)
url.searchParams.append('endpoint', language)

const correctURL = url.href + '&endpoint=' + endpoint
```

So my question goes like this: **how to pass parentheses in the URL or how to make this code better?**

Comment: Parentheses “()” may be used as such in the query part of URL. It is allowable, but not necessary, to encode them, as “%28” and “%29”.

Answer (score 2):

> Parentheses “()” may be used as such in the query part of URL. It is allowable, but not necessary, to encode them, as “%28” and “%29”.

---

You can use `YOURURL.replace(/\(/g, "%28").replace(/\)/g, "%29")` to replace all brackets by the correct URL encoding,

```js
const country = 'us'
const language = 'en'
const anchor = 0
const consumerChannelId = 'd9a5bc42-4b9c-4976-858a-f159cf99c647'

const count = 24

const remoteSearch= `/product_feed/rollup_threads/v2?filter=marketplace(${country})&filter=language(${language})&anchor=${anchor}&consumerChannelId=${consumerChannelId}&count=${count}`
  .replace(/\(/g, "%28").replace(/\)/g, "%29"); // use regex to replace

const url = new URL('https://example.xyz/v1')
url.searchParams.append('queryid', 'products')
url.searchParams.append('country', country)
url.searchParams.append('language', language)
url.searchParams.append('endpoint', remoteSearch)

console.log(url);
```

Comment: I don't understand why we need to replace parentheses in remoteSearch, if searchParams will encode them anyway. In this case we got (for example):  `marketplace%2528us%2529%`
It looks like we are adding a new wrapper.
Without replace, searchParams encode them like:

`marketplace%28us%29`
but i need pass them to URL in this manner:
`marketplace(us)`

Remote API doesnt accept encode Parentheses

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use `encodeURIComponent()` it's built-in function but in your case, it might not be useful you can create a separate function to do that

```
function encodeNonURIComponent(url) {
  return encodeURIComponent(url).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) {
    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
  });
}
```

Comment: Maybe I expressed myself incorrectly, but I just don't need to encode parentheses. For these purposes, my current solution uses encodeURIComponent. But then I have to add the endpoint parameter with the value remoteSearch using string concatenation (because the searchParams method encodes parentheses - and I don't need it)